# Samsung S7 (Oreo) BLE scan and disconnect problems

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, disconnect

Our app needs to connect with BLE device to collecting data, the code has two problems when running on Samsung S7 (model name SM-930W8, Android 8.0):

1. BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback) fails to find our device (can be solved if we passes an empty filters and filter by our code later on);
2. BluetoothGatt.disconnect() will not disconnect with Samsung S7 with our device. We use compileSdkVersion 29, minSdkVersion 26.
   This app works on Samsung S7 Active, Samsung S8 (SM-G950W), also works on Samsung S6 Edge if downgrade the minSdkVersion to 24. I also tried to turn off 'Nearby device scanning' on Samsung S7, did not work.

```
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();
mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
```

```
mGatt.disconnect();
```

Comment: we can’t see what filters you are setting....can you add them? Otherwise it is impossible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: The filters we pass in is an empty array, the sensor could be found, connected and communicated. ```mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);```

Comment: As a work around, send reset command from phone to disconnect SM-930W8 with our sensor. For other phone, no such extra step to disconnect with the sensor.